# Java Nested While Loops and Factorials Beginner

Tags: java, while-loop, nested-loops, factorial

I'm working on nest while loops. I began with an initial while loop, that printed out the factorial of a given number. The code for that is below. I am now trying to to add the second loop, which would 10 numbers, (i.e if the number 4 was inputted, it would print out the factorial for numbers 4 through to 14). I know the loop should begin above what I already have, but I don't really know where to go from there. I've inserted what I think is the beginning of the first loop.
I'm new to coding so any and all help is appreciated

Existing code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in)

        while (count <10)
        {
            int number = myScanner.nextInt();
            int fact = 1;
            int i = 1;

            while(i<=number)
            {
                fact = fact * i;
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println("Factorial of "+number+" is: "+fact);
        }
   `}
}
```

Comment: Format your code

Comment: next challenge, a little optimization: `5! = 4! * 5`, that is, when calculating `5!` there is no need to calculate `1*2*3*4` since this is already the result from previous calculation (`4!`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-You need to move the `number = myScanner.nextInt()` outside of the loop so that it won't ask for new input every iteration.

-You need to define `count` (`int count = 0`;)

-Loop until `count` is `<=` 10.

-Increment `count` and `number` at the end of the loop:

```
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int count = 0;
int number = myScanner.nextInt();
while (count <=10) {

     int fact = 1;
     int i = 1;

     while(i<=number) {         
         fact = fact * i;
         i++;
     }
     System.out.println("Factorial of "+number+" is: "+fact);
     number++;
     count++;
}
```

***Output:*** (With 4 as input)

```
Factorial of 4 is: 24
Factorial of 5 is: 120
Factorial of 6 is: 720
Factorial of 7 is: 5040
Factorial of 8 is: 40320
Factorial of 9 is: 362880
Factorial of 10 is: 3628800
Factorial of 11 is: 39916800
Factorial of 12 is: 479001600
Factorial of 13 is: 1932053504
Factorial of 14 is: 1278945280
```

**However** we can optimize this a lot. 5! is equal to 4! * 5. So knowing this we can simply not reset `i` and `fact` inside the loop. If we enter 4, after the first iteration, `fact` will be equal to 4!, and `i` will be equal to 5. If simply don't reset them, on the next iteration we will simply multiply `fact` (4!) by 5. Then `i` will become six and the `while` loop will terminate. Then this will continue until the outer `while` loop terminates.

```
int fact = 1;
int i = 1;
while (count <=10) {       
     while(i<=number) {            
         fact = fact * i;
         i++;
     }
     System.out.println("Factorial of "+number+" is: "+fact);
     number++;
     count++;
}
```

With 4 as the input this will reduce the amount of iterations in the inner `while` loop from 99 to 14.